# Get number as dialed in the native dialer of Android

Tags: android, phone-call

Can I get the number as entered by the user in native dialer on the run. I want to get the digit one by one as he enters in the native dialer programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the key events from the native dialer as it would create a serious security issues and dialer could be easily spy on.